# Sunsopt Solr Group not working with fulltext search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

Sunsopt Solr fulltext search and Group not working

```
a = User.search { fulltext("") { highlight :document_text, :fragment_size => 300, :group => document_id }}


--- SOLR Request (9.7ms)  [ path=select parameters={fq: ["type:User"], start: 0, rows: 30, q: "*:*"} ]

 => <Sunspot::Search:{:fq=>["type:User"], :start=>0, :rows=>30, :q=>"*:*"}> 

 2.1.2 :081 > a.group(:document_id)
 => nil
```

i tried like this also

```
 User.search { fulltext("terms", :group => "doc_name") { highlight :document_text, :fragment_size => 300 }}
```

getting same

Answer (score 0):

your `user.rb` should also have the searcheable block for solr.

```
##for sunspot search..something like this...
    searchable do
      text :username, :boost => 3
      text :first_name,:last_name
    end
```

Comment: yes searchable do
    integer :id
    time :created_at
    time :updated_at
    text :document_text, stored: true
    integer :page_no
    integer :document_id
    string :doc_name
  end